# Relevance & Purpose Question

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-in-context

I am really confused with question number 12. Options A and D both make sense.

Option A because the gardener has a direct reference and is receiving gift, which is also a food. The information thus has to do something with the context.

Option D because eels are mentioned. Gardner is also related to eels.

I chose option A because I thought that "delicacy" has a negative meaning, and why a grandmother will play a prank on Gardner as he doesn't like eels? Maybe, I misunderstood.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *delicacy* here is not something negative. The meaning is defined in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/delicacy) as:

> **delicacy** (*noun*) `FOOD` something especially rare or expensive that is good to eat:

The clue is found in Sentence 12: the grandmother wanted to give the gardener a food gift. There is another clue at the end of the narrative, when the gardener begins cooking the eel.

Me, I don't particularly care for eel. But, evidently, the gardener likes eel very much; otherwise, the grandmother would not have presented the eel to the gardener as a gift.